# Exercising clean code

Tags: powershell, script, services, powershell-ise, azure-devops

I have a script that if kept on the same line, it'll be quite annoying to edit. But at the point at where I want to break line, I get the error when running,

> -ApplicationParameter : The term '-ApplicationParameter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
> was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I would just like for this to have that clean look, as I will be editing it with every deployment.

```
# Installs the application
New-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName $ApplicationName -ApplicationTypeName $ApplicationType -ApplicationTypeVersion $ApplicationVersion |
-ApplicationParameter @{
 Logic_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "LOCAL";
 Logic_InstanceCount = "1";
 Logic_ServiceUser = "switchcommerce\localdevgmsa";
 Data_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "LOCAL";
 Data_PartitionCount = "1";
 Data_MinReplicaSetSize = "3";
 Data_TargetReplicaSetSize = "3";
 Data_ServiceUser = "switchcommerce\localdevgmsa";
}
```

I've tried using the '|' symbol and `n and` r but no luck. Is there a way to keep it looking like this but make sure it'll run? Or are you just unable to start a line with a parameter: -ApplicationParameter

Comment: What research have you done? The | symbol is the pipe, not the line break, and PowerShell does support line breaks in cmdlet argument strings.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608144/how-to-split-long-commands-over-multiple-lines-in-powershell

Comment: This is why PowerShell Splatting exists.  [about_splattig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3). See also: [Bye Bye backtick](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line.html). PS has many common / built-in line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think I got it. I went with:

```
# Installs the application
New-ServiceFabricApplication `
    -ApplicationName $ApplicationName `
    -ApplicationTypeName $ApplicationType `
    -ApplicationTypeVersion $ApplicationVersion `
    -ApplicationParameter @{
        Logic_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "LOCAL";
        Logic_InstanceCount = "1";
        Logic_ServiceUser = "switchcommerce\localdevgmsa";
        Data_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "LOCAL";
        Data_PartitionCount = "1";
        Data_MinReplicaSetSize = "3";
        Data_TargetReplicaSetSize = "3";
        Data_ServiceUser = "switchcommerce\localdevgmsa";
    }
```

That seems to have worked. Figuring out some kinks with the actual parameter values now. Thank you!